# How can I use EWS to move items to a folder?

Tags: powershell, exchangewebservices

The following PowerShell script as been adapted to our situation.
It read all emails in the Inbox folder then extract attachments

It working well but I would like to move items to the "/Processed" mailbox root folder. This folder is not a subfolder of the Inbox folder :

```
Mailbox
L Inbox
L Processed
L Sent Items
L Deleted Items
```

If I use the following line

```
[VOID]$miMailItems.Move("DeletedItems")
```

However, it doesn't work as expected. It deleted the email but in my personal mailbox, not the "john" mailbox !

So, can you help me to

1. correct the code to move items to the john mailbox when using the code `[VOID]$miMailItems.Move("DeletedItems")`
2. let me know how I can simply moving items to the john "Processed" mailbox subfolder?

```cs
$MailboxName = 'john@domain.com'
$downloadDirectory = '\\share\'
$dllpath = "C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange Server\V15\Bin\Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.dll"
[VOID][Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile($dllpath)
$service = New-Object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeService([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeVersion]::Exchange2013)
$sidbind = "LDAP://<SID=" + (Get-ADUser exchadmin).SID.ToString() + ">"
$aceuser = [ADSI]$sidbind
$service.AutodiscoverUrl($aceuser.mail.ToString())
$folderid = new-object  Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.FolderId([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.WellKnownFolderName]::Inbox,$MailboxName)
$InboxFolder = [Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Folder]::Bind($service,$folderid)
$Sfha = new-object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.SearchFilter+IsEqualTo([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.EmailMessageSchema]::HasAttachments, $true)
$sfCollection = new-object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.SearchFilter+SearchFilterCollection([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.LogicalOperator]::And);
$sfCollection.add($Sfha)
$view = new-object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ItemView(2000)
$frFolderResult = $InboxFolder.FindItems($sfCollection,$view)
foreach ($miMailItems in $frFolderResult.Items){ 
    $miMailItems.Load()
    foreach($attach in $miMailItems.Attachments){
        $attach.Load()
        $fiFile = new-object System.IO.FileStream(($downloadDirectory + “\” + (Get-Date).Millisecond + "_" + $attach.Name.ToString()), [System.IO.FileMode]::Create)
        $fiFile.Write($attach.Content, 0, $attach.Content.Length)
        $fiFile.Close()    
    }
    $miMailItems.isread = $true
    $miMailItems.Update([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ConflictResolutionMode]::AlwaysOverwrite)

    # The following send items to my personal "Deleted Items" folder instead of the john mailbox...
    [VOID]$miMailItems.Move("DeletedItems")

    # How can I send items to the "/Processed" folder of the john mailbox ?
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The Move method will take the FolderId of the folder you want to move the Item to so you need to first find the  FolderId of the folder you want to move to eg

```cs
function FolderIdFromPath{
    param (
            $FolderPath = "$( throw 'Folder Path is a mandatory Parameter' )",
            $SmtpAddress = "$( throw 'Folder Path is a mandatory Parameter' )"
          )
    process{
        ## Find and Bind to Folder based on Path  
        #Define the path to search should be seperated with \  
        #Bind to the MSGFolder Root  
        $folderid = new-object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.FolderId([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.WellKnownFolderName]::MsgFolderRoot,$SmtpAddress)   
        $tfTargetFolder = [Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Folder]::Bind($service,$folderid)  
        #Split the Search path into an array  
        $fldArray = $FolderPath.Split("\") 
         #Loop through the Split Array and do a Search for each level of folder 
        for ($lint = 1; $lint -lt $fldArray.Length; $lint++) { 
            #Perform search based on the displayname of each folder level 
            $fvFolderView = new-object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.FolderView(1) 
            $SfSearchFilter = new-object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.SearchFilter+IsEqualTo([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.FolderSchema]::DisplayName,$fldArray[$lint]) 
            $findFolderResults = $service.FindFolders($tfTargetFolder.Id,$SfSearchFilter,$fvFolderView) 
            if ($findFolderResults.TotalCount -gt 0){ 
                foreach($folder in $findFolderResults.Folders){ 
                    $tfTargetFolder = $folder                
                } 
            } 
            else{ 
                "Error Folder Not Found"  
                $tfTargetFolder = $null  
                break  
            }     
        }  
        if($tfTargetFolder -ne $null){
            return $tfTargetFolder.Id.UniqueId.ToString()
        }
        else{
            throw "Folder not found"
        }
    }
}
#Example use
$fldId = FolderIdFromPath -FolderPath "\Processed" -SmtpAddress $aceuser.mail.ToString()
$SubFolderId =  new-object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.FolderId($fldId)
$SubFolder = [Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Folder]::Bind($service,$SubFolderId)
```

then just change

```
[VOID]$miMailItems.Move($SubFolder.Id)
```